# Fade in Slideshow with Slide Animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, flexslider

Does anyone have any experience with FlexSlider? Or jQuery in general?

I'm using the FlexSlider slideshow script and I've customised it to my needs here: http://www.davidpottrell.co.uk/slide/demo/

My question is, does anyone know how to have the slideshow fade in and use the slide animation for the slides? At the moment I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    start: function(slider){
      $('.flexslider').removeClass('loading');
    }
  });
});
```

This allows for the slideshow to fade in, but it also forces the slides to fade to the next. I'd like it to slide.

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/HGEDz/1/

Comment: please create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ you'll get much more help

Comment: I tried to - It just won't work :/
http://jsfiddle.net/HGEDz/

Answer (score 0):

two little things I changed on your fiddle

first $(document).ready(function... (is may just because of the fiddle) and the animation:"slide",

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.flexslider').flexslider({
         animation: "slide",
         start: function(slider){
             $('.flexslider').removeClass('loading');
         }
     });
 });
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/HGEDz/1/

Comment: Ah right okay - I'll update my fiddle link to this one. But you see my problem now? The slide animation works between slides. But it's also applied to the entire slideshow when the page loads. I'd like it to fade in instead. Thanks for the fiddle fix though :)

Comment: so when page is loaded fadeIn the gallery and than slide the slides?

Comment: Correct :)
Basically I'm after a loading effect. Instead of the slide sliding in, I'd like it to fade fast (hardly noticeable) But enough to make it an easy transition.

Comment: That's certainly the closest to what I'm after yes! There's only one issue with using display:none though. Any element under it is temporarily placed above the slideshow until it fades in. So close!

Comment: Would {visibility:hidden;} be good practise? Or is using position:absolute a better option? Either way this is great! I'm implement it now and play around with it. Thanks a lot Caramba, you've been a great help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31898/discussion-between-david-and-caramba)